# Does anyone know if NetBeans 6.x can be used with Java SE 6 on Leopard?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, osx-leopard

Java SE 6 (64 bit only) is now on OS X and that is a good thing. As I understand it since Eclipse is still Carbon and thus 32 bit, it cannot be used for 1.6 on Leopard, only 1.5.

Does anyone know if NetBeans 6.x can be used with Java SE 6 on Leopard utilizing its JVM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to.

A number of blogs have reported running Netbeans on 1.6 as well as the the problems they had with earlier versions of NB. The NB issue tracker also has a number of bugs that have been fixed that affected 1.6 on Mac OS.

If you have trouble getting it to run, you might also try [the Netbeans forum](http://www.nabble.com/Netbeans.org-f2602.html).

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse works with java 1.6, kinda.  Ecplipse runs using the 1.5 vm, but it can compile code for 1.6 using the 1.6 java compiler.  I have used netbeans for 1.6 development and it seems alright.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it yet, but can't think of any reason why not.